# SSL ERROR. WWW domain name not working in my server error browser: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: domain, https

Edit:
The problem was that I set only one SSL for the domain, but not one for the www.domain, i solved this by setting both in the same prompt. After that both worked.

Depends on what kind if SSL you using the proceed will be diferent.

---

having this issue where my domain will only conect to the https or http, but if you type it directly or the www it will not connect to the dns servers and give error:

> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Must be something simple that im missing

EDIT1:

I was able to get it to access just with name so far. (dont know what I did maybe servers fault...)

As for the www, I tried setting a www name pointing to my server from the domain service, thats all I could come up with, this after getting A type record on my own system pointing to WWW and my domain. so far did not solve the problem.

EDIT2
here is what i did by my side:

> www.   A   Default     myip
>
> www.   A   Default     domainip
>
> www.mysite.com.    PTR     Default     mysite.com.
>
> mysite.com.    A   Default     188.79.168.123
>
> www.mysite.com.    A   Default     188.79.168.123

Edit3: I can now sucessfully ping it back to my server, now i may have to wait for the adress to propagate.

What i did is to add the full www. Adress to the dns list on the domain provider, I can open the website now from 4g, but people for example in the US may not be able (im in europe).

Also seems like the problem has to do with how i setup my ssl certificates, seems like i have 2 certificates one for the domain and other for the www. adress, causing some error.

As mentioned by answer i ran this using my phone on 4g:

> [~]: host mysute
>
> www.mysite.com has address 188.79.168.123

Seems solved.

Comment: What are you using to connect to the server? Where is the server hosted? What services are running on it?

Comment: What is your domain name?

Comment: @zymhan usually i have to use anything outside the network, since i dont route a vpn, i use 4g or other vpns to test it. The server is hosted on a computer of mine running lamp.

Comment: @MichaelHampton darkmaze.tk

Comment: I think its not working anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set up a DNS address record for `www`. That's why you can't reach it. It doesn't exist.

```
$ host darkmaze.tk
darkmaze.tk has address 188.79.168.123
$ host www.darkmaze.tk
Host www.darkmaze.tk not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Comment: thanks, is this something i do by my side or domain service side

Comment: You do this with your DNS provider.

Comment: [~]: host www.darkmaze.tk www.darkmaze.tk has address 188.79.168.123, seems solved